# Strange behaviour in assigning a list of np.array to a subset of rows of a DataFrame by *loc*

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I found pandas works differently between assigning a list of native values (like int or char) and np.arrays to a subset of rows in a DataFrame by *loc*.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['xxx','yyy',np.nan,np.nan],'score':[100,80,np.nan,np.nan]})
# This line works
df.loc[df['name'].isnull(),'rank']=['F','F']  
# This line does not work
df.loc[df['name'].isnull(),'rank'] = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([5,6])]

# This line works
df['rank']=['A','B','F','F']. 
# Very strange that this line also works.
df['rank'] = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([5,6]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([5,6])]
```

I wanted to assign a list of np.array to a selection of rows by *loc* as in the 3rd line above, but it didn't work. Strangely it works to assign to a list of array to all rows. My question is how I can assign a list of arrays to a subset of rows in a neat way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think it is not recommended, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17027):

> I think we could use a doc section stating storing nested lists/arrays inside a pandas object is preferred to be avoided, showing the downsides (perf, memory use) and a worked out example of an alternative. This seems to be earned knowledge that many have, but not sure we do a good job stating it clearly.
>
> Closely related, might also benefit from a little section encouraging use of Python core data structures when appropriate.

Possible solution, is add another list `[]`, but sometimes also failed for me:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isnull(),'rank'] = [[np.array([1,2]),np.array([5,6])]]

print (df)
  name  score    rank
0  xxx  100.0     NaN
1  yyy   80.0     NaN
2  NaN    NaN  [1, 2]
3  NaN    NaN  [5, 6]
```

Better solution, but still hacky is create helper `Series` with filtered index values:

```
m = df['name'].isnull()
df.loc[m,'rank'] = pd.Series([np.array([1,2]), np.array([5,6])], index=df.index[m])
print (df)
  name  score    rank
0  xxx  100.0     NaN
1  yyy   80.0     NaN
2  NaN    NaN  [1, 2]
3  NaN    NaN  [5, 6]
```

Comment: Ah you won! I almost answered the same :)

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain why the 5th line works well without extra [] ? and why for native values the extra [] also is not needed ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, I also found that the same code may result differently after multiple times running.